# How to remove special characters from strings but keep underscores in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a string that is something like "info_A!__B????????C_*".  I wan to remove the special characters from it but keep underscores and letters.  I tried with [:word:] (ASCII letters and _) character set, but it says "invalid character set".  any idea how to handle this ?  Thanks.

```
text="info_!_????????_*"
if [ -z `echo $text | tr -dc "[:word:]"` ]
......
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `bash` parameter expansion:

```
$ var='info_A!__B????????C_*'

$ echo "${var//[^[:alnum:]_]/}"
info_A__BC_
```

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` one-liner  would be

```
sed 's/[^[:alnum:]_]//g' <<< 'info_!????????*'
```

gives you

```
info_
```

An `awk` one-liner would be

```
awk '{gsub(/[^[:alnum:]_]/,"",$0)} 1' <<< 'info_!??A_??????*pi9ngo^%$_mingo745'
```

gives you

```
info_A_pi9ngo_mingo745
```

If you don't wish to have numbers in the output then change `:alnum:` to `:alpha:`.

Answer (score 1):

My `tr` doesn't understand `[:word:]`. I had to do like this:

```
$ x=$(echo 'info_A!__B????????C_*' | tr -cd '[:alnum:]_')
$ echo $x
info_A__BC_
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if its robust way but it worked for your sample text.

sed one-liner:

```
echo "SamPlE_@tExT%, really ?" | sed -e 's/[^a-z^A-Z|^_]//g'
SamPlE_tExTreally
```